# Is there a way of telling apt to run when it can - when the previous instance has finished?

Tags: apt, bash, software-installation

I am quite absent minded, and I forget everything I want to install - especially after a restart

Is there a way that I can set another command to run (in a separate terminal, of course) when the currently running instance of `apt` has finished?

I expect this could be done by repeatedly trying to run the command, but I'm looking for something more like this:

```
WHEN apt EXIT = True; do run next-apt-command
```

I also expect that it could check the lock file, to see if it is available?

Comment: Ahh I was sure it must have been asked before!

Comment: @tim WHEN apt EXIT = True; do run next-apt-command it is working?

Comment: @khanthegeek no, that was the type of thing I was looking for. look at the linked answer.